# antlr to parse stringand return splitted string

Tags: antlr

i am working on antlr to split string { city } | { country } | {continent}

it should return me 
city,country,continent

My Grammar is:

```
splitrule : ( OPENING_BRACES . CLOSING_BRACES ) SEPARATOR (OPENING_BRACES . CLOSING_BRACES); // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ; // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; 
SEPARATOR               :'|';
OPENING_BRACES          : '{';
CLOSING_BRACES          : '}';
ANY_CHARACTER           :'.';
```

let me know how should i make it to match any number of character and return city , country or city country , continent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following grammar:

```
splitrule : item ( SEPARATOR item )* ;
item : OPENING_BRACE ID CLOSING_BRACE ;

ID : [a-z]+ ; // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; 
SEPARATOR               :'|';
OPENING_BRACE           : '{';
CLOSING_BRACE           : '}';
ANY_CHARACTER           :'.';
```

If several words are allowed between braces, replace `ID` with `ID+` in the `item` rule.